# How to compare two very large number

Tags: c++11

given two integers a and (0 <= a,b <=100^100).

If a is bigger, print "a is bigger than b"

If b is bigger, print "b is bigger than a"

Else, print "They are equal"

I don't exactly know how to solve this problem when the range is upto 100^100. Is there any fine method to solve this problem in C++ ?

Comment: Think of numbers as strings and then comparing could be one way.

Comment: As an initial matter, define "given". In what form are they "given" to your program?